# limit of complicated sum that wolfram alpha cannot solve

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Let $1 \leq d\leq \frac{1}{2}\log^3(n) \sqrt{n}$.

We would like to show that for any such $d$ we have

$$\sum_{x=0}^{\lceil \log^6(n) d \rceil}\left(\log^3(n) \sqrt{n}\right)^{d+x} e^{-\frac{\log^4(n)}{\sqrt{n}}d \left(\frac{n}{\log(n)}-x\right)} \rightarrow 0$$

as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Can you help me with this? Is this possible? If yes, how, if no, why not? If not, can we show it for some values of $d$? I have no idea how to attack such a problem and unfortunately, Wolfram Alpha cannot 
help me! Thank you a lot!

Comment: What's the intended interpretation of the non-integer upper limit of the summation?

Comment: oh, well then let just make it integer by ceiling. Sorry for that, I will change it.